# Is it possible to have a quick look to org-todo in splitted window?

Tags: org-mode

I believe this can be done but I couldn't find the right wrapper package or approach for it.

I just want have a quick look to `TODO` and close it. Similar approach is done in `org-journal`. I am using [org-journal](https://github.com/bastibe/org-journal) to keep my journal entries. Can the same usage mechanism applied to [org-todo](http://ergoemacs.org/emacs/emacs_org_mode_for_todo.html), where:

`org-journal-new-entry` opens half frame windows showing journal entries.

- Like `org-journal-new-entry`, `.todo` file will be opened on a half window and cursor's focus is on it.
- With C-x C-s it will be closed like `(define-key org-journal-mode-map (kbd "C-x C-s") 'org-journal-save-entry-and-exit)` does.

Comment: Have you tried org-capture?

Comment: seems like ` org-capture` is the one but it does not close itself after a save is done :-(

Comment: Don't save normally, instead `C-c C-c` https://orgmode.org/manual/Using-capture.html#Using-capture

Comment: Ah I binded `C-c C-c` for something else :( It also keeps asking for `[t]     Task` but I want jump to my base default TODO file no matter what

Comment: `C-c C-c` is `org-capture-finalize`, you can bind that to something else if you like. To capture for just that template you can `(defun my/org-task-capture () (interactive) (org-capture nil "t"))`

Comment: Can it open the saved templates? like each time I do org-capture it keeps opening a new file

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean.  I think maybe you should search for / ask new questions and read the docs if you're interested in org-capture

Comment: Like it dumps each TODO into a file each time but it does not open the history of TODOs I added before, I want to see the previously added TODOs as well